# Should we have an observation-campaign tag and what is good usage advice for it?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag, tagging

I've just asked [Is there a collection or list of all planned observations of 99942 Apophis during it's close pass to Earth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43190/7982) and added a new [observation-campaign](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/observation-campaign) tag to it.

We have many questions that contain references to observing campaigns of one sort or another.

My understanding is that it is anything between a rally for amateur observers to try to photograph something to a highly coordinated and preplanned observing plan for ground and space observatories and facilities, but that's just my impression.

To establish more information on that I've asked the companion question in the main site: [Is an "observation campaign" well recognized thing in Astronomy? Is it self-declared? Are there standard ways to announce or coordinate?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43191/7982)

**Question:** Should we have an observation-campaign tag and what what would be good usage advice for it?

- [What is the extent of the "worldwide campaign" to observe near-earth object 2012 TC4?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/22081/7982)
- [Why weren't the Hubble light-echo images of V838 Monocerotis supplemented by ground telescopes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/14781/7982)
- [How does V838 Monocerotis look today? Any subsequent light echo images, or is the party over?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28239/7982)
- [How often are radio telescopes used to measure parallax? When was this first done?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39002/7982)
- ["Who saw" the binary neutron star merger first? What was the sequence of events? (GRB/GW170817)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23187/7982)
- [How (the heck) was this photo of Venus at inferior conjunction (between us and the Sun) taken?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23271/7982)
- [Could stellar occultations be used to survey Kuiper belt objects?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29033/7982)
- [Do some comets spin? If so, how fast?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41214/7982)
- [How to find out which Messier objects are in the Kepler/K2 fields?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18196/7982)
- [What complementary observation campaigns have looked at Kepler's field of view?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19146/7982)
- [What might a CN filter be in the context of comet watching? Is it showing dust, or gas, or something else?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28700/7982)
- [How can a Grade-11 Student avail TESS data and learn to process?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34952/7982)
- [What does "forward facing" mean for space telescopes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18351/7982)

Comment: I am aware that there are [SOFIA campaigns](https://www.dlr.de/blogs/en/all-blog-posts/SOFIA-s-record-breaking-campaign-in-New-Zealand.aspx/searchtagid-57071/), and I heard about a neutrino observation campaign as well (used possibly colloquially by friends in the field - I do not have a written reference for that). My defintion would be something like a  `coordinated observation effort for a certain time interval`, but that's just my personal definition.